# create prop with id value pair in vue using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

In typescript, i have seen the prop is initialized like this below in vue component.

```
@Prop({ type: Object }) tabDetails: tabDetailsTypes
```

This tabDetailsTypes is like :

```
export interface tabDetailsTypes {
  label: string
  name: string
  count: number | string
```

Same thing i want to create prop in vue component by using JavaScript like this.

```
props: {
  serverUrls: {
   required: true,
            type: Object,
            default: () => {
             label: '',
             name: '',
             count: 1
     }
  }
}
```

It is correct syntax or what is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: To return and inline Object with ES6 arrows functions, you should escape the braces with parenthesis like: `default: () => ({ ... })`. Another way is using `return` statement:  `default: () => { return { ... } }`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by that to create a prop that the behavior follows Typescript's behavior where your IDE would complaint if you defined something that is unavailable or different by the type on the given properties, or if you want it to serve the available option through intellisense, I don't think you can do that on Javascript.

And as you edited the question, if you want to set the default value, you don't need the `required` property. Remove that, add braces around the object and all is good.

```js
props: {
  serverUrls: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({
      label: 'the default label',
      name: 'the default name',
      id: 1,
    }),
  }
},
mounted() {
  console.log(this.serverUrls)
},
```

[Here is the working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-diffie-yu8bx?file=/src/App.vue:468-513)